# One or more items in the folder you synchronized do not match. To resolve the conflicts, open the items, and then try this operation again

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Why am I receiving this error message? It was working fine not too long ago and when I ran the code, it gives me the error message: "One or more items in the folder you synchronized do not match. To resolve the conflicts, open the items, and then try this operation again."

```
'create sub
Sub Export_TaskItems()
Dim NS As NameSpace
Dim TaskFolder As Folder
Dim Item As Object
Dim TaskItem As TaskItem

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlwb As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim iRow As Long

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlwb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
Set xlws = xlwb.Worksheets(1)

Set NS = Session
Set TaskFolder = NS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderToDo)

'this line request the excel table range and add an array of values
xlws.Range("A1").Resize(1, 6).Value = Array("Status", "Start Date", "Due Date", "Task Name", "Importance", "Category")
'the iRow being assigned to row number two which is the row we will insert the information
iRow = 2

'for loop to handle the information/date
For Each Item In TaskFolder.Items
    If Item.Class = olTask Then
    
        Set TaskItem = Item
        
        xlws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Convert_Status(TaskItem.Status)
        xlws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = TaskItem.StartDate
        xlws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = TaskItem.DueDate
        xlws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = TaskItem.Subject
        xlws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Convert_Importance(TaskItem.Importance)
        xlws.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = TaskItem.Categories
        
        iRow = iRow + 1
    End If
    
Next Item

xlApp.Visible = True

Set xlApp = Nothing


End Sub

Public Function Convert_Status(ByVal Status_Value As Integer) As String

On Error Resume Next
Convert_Status = Array("Not Started", "In Progress", "Complete", "Waiting", "Deferred")(Status_Value)

End Function

Public Function Convert_Importance(ByVal Importance_Value As Integer) As String

On Error Resume Next
Convert_Importance = Array("Low", "Normal", "High")(Importance_Value)

End Function
```

Comment: This macro is VBA attempting to pull my task list in outlook into excel

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good. I didn't notice anything strange in the code posted. However, to bring your changes to the server I'd suggest synchronizing changes with the server-side. You can use the [SyncObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.syncobjects) object which contains a set of `SyncObject` objects representing the Send/Receive groups for a user. To begin synchronizing a user's folders using the specified Send\Receive group you can use the [SyncObject.Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.syncobject.start) method:

```
Public Sub Sync() 
 Dim nsp As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim sycs As Outlook.SyncObjects 
 Dim syc As Outlook.SyncObject 
 Dim i As Integer 
 Dim strPrompt As Integer 
 Set nsp = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 Set sycs = nsp.SyncObjects 
 For i = 1 To sycs.Count 
   Set syc = sycs.Item(i) 
   strPrompt = MsgBox("Do you wish to synchronize " & syc.Name &"?", vbYesNo) 
   If strPrompt = vbYes Then 
     syc.Start 
   End If 
 Next 
End Sub
```